# How to convert two list to json format

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask, deep-learning

I'm not able to convert two list to json format.

i have tried to convert two list to dictionary format and then converted to json format but duplicate key arenot there which i want too.

```
    p = np.argmax(y[:416], axis=-1)
    # print(p)
    flat_list_te = padd_to_2d_senti[:416]
    flat_list_test = [item for sublist in flat_list_te for item in sublist]
    # print(flat_list_test)
    # flat_list = [item for sublist in y_te[i] for item in sublist]
    flat_list_pred = [item for sublist in p for item in sublist]
    key = []
    value = []
    for w,pred in zip(flat_list_test,flat_list_pred):
        predicted_tag = idx2tag[pred]

        if predicted_tag !='O':
            a.append(w)
            b.append(idx2tag[pred])
    test_pred = dict(zip(key,value))
expected output:
    key = ["phone","age","class","class"]
    value = [123,4,5,6]
    dic = {"phone":123,"age":4,"class":5,"class":6}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each key within a `dict` needs to be unique. So this dictionary is not possible:

`dic = {"phone":123,"age":4,"class":5,"class":6}`

`"class"` exists twice.

Possible solutions:

- rename one of the `"class"`strings to something unique
- create a `tuple` for the value of key `"class"`, e.g. `dic = {"class":(5, 6)}`